# aspectj-maven-plugin during test

Tags: unit-testing, maven, aspectj

I'm having probem with `aspectj-maven-plugin`. I only need it for unit tests.

You can see my plugin configuration below (no configuration is defined in parent POMs, I have already checked the 'Effective POM').

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.4</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>default-compile</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>test-compile</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

However, whenever I try a `mvn clean deploy` or `mvn clean test` I get compilation errors because plugin execution is skipped:

```
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4:test-compile (default-compile) @ jcz-persistence-aspectj ---
[INFO] Skipping execution because of 'skip' option
```

Every suggestion is welcome!

Stefano

Comment: I just tried the exact same configuration and it works without issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do a [test-compile](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/test-compile-mojo.html). Which will weave the test classes alone. Try using just **[compile](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html)** as the goal.

> ```
>         <executions>
>             <execution>
>                 <goals>
>                     <goal>compile</goal>
>                 </goals>
>             </execution>
>         </executions>
> ```

Comment: Have you read the question? `I only need it for unit tests.` it says.

Comment: If your case aspect is needed only for your unit test, then what is use in going for it? As I ahve seen, people may need to skip the aspect for test and for normal compilation they need aspect. Thats why there are only two goals test-compile and compile. But in your case you need the reverse.

Comment: The point is that I'm testing an external libraries to see if everything works as expected, in a compliant environment. An example could be testing classes that make use of Spring `@Transactional` annotation. However, I don't want to weave main classes as this is up to the application context in which they will be used (could use LTW instead CTW, for example). Another example is testing aspects to see if pointcuts are detected correctly and advices do what they are expected to.